# Need SQL select query to find duplicates and return min and max rows

Tags: sql, select

I have the sql query as below.

```
(SELECT 
    height
    ,width
    ,ROUND(height / 0.0254, 0) AS "H1"
    ,FLOOR((width * 2) / 0.0254) AS "W1"
FROM iclr_max_dim_results mdim
    ,iclr_request req
WHERE mdim.request_oid = req.oid
    AND req.request_number = 102017
    AND req.version_number = 52731
GROUP BY height
ORDER BY height DESC
                ) A
    )
```

Below is the result of the query.

```
height   | width    | H1    |  W1  
-----------------------------------------
<hr>
6.0223   | 0.1003   | 237   |  7 
6.0198   | 0.2435   | 237   | 19 
6.0185   | 0.3151   | 237   | 24 
5.9944   | 1.6759   | 236   | 131
5.9931   | 1.6779   | 236   | 132
5.9576   | 1.7016   | 235   | 133
5.9563   | 1.7024   | 235   | 134
```

If we see the last two columns H1 and W1 in the first three rows, the value 237 repeats with 7, 19, 24 respectively. I will need to return only the rows min and max W1 value for H1.

Here, in this case the result shall be as below. We eliminated 237 | 19 since 7 and 24 are min and max for 237.

```
6.0223   | 0.1003   | 237   |  7 
6.0185   | 0.3151   | 237   | 24 
5.9944   | 1.6759   | 236   | 131
5.9931   | 1.6779   | 236   | 132
5.9576   | 1.7016   | 235   | 133
5.9563   | 1.7024   | 235   | 134
```

How should I edit the SQL qyery to archieve this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query can be this:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (...) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT H1, MIN(W1) as w1_min, MAX(W1) as w1_max
    FROM (...) c
    GROUP BY H1
  ) b ON b.H1 = a.H1 AND (b.w1_min = a.W1 OR b.w1_max = a.W1)
```

Replace `...` with your original query or cretate VIEW from your original query and replace `(...)` with views name.